# SoapUI/Groovy - How to copy a node with a new name in the same dom?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, groovy, soapui

I am trying to get some data from a SoapUI response to generate a new SoapUI request. This is the reponse I have in input:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetDataResponse>
      <return>
        <dataType1>
          <img>...</img>
        </dataType1>
        <dataType1>
          <img>...</img>
        </dataType1>
        <dataType1>
          <img>...</img>
        </dataType1>
        <dataType2>
          <date1>2018-01-30T00:00:00.000+01:00</date1>
          <img>...</img>
        </dataType2>
        <dataType2>
          <date1>2018-01-30T00:00:00.000+01:00</date1>
          <img>...</img>
        </dataType2>
        <dataType3>
        </dataType3>
      </return>
    </GetDataResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The output I am trying to generate is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <process>
      <workflow1>
        <dataType1>
          <img>...</img>
        </dataType1>
        <dataType1>
          <img>...</img>
        </dataType1>
        <dataType1>
          <img>...</img>
        </dataType1>
        <dataType2>
          <date1>2018-01-30T00:00:00.000+01:00</date1>
          <date2>2018-01-30T00:00:00.000+01:00</date2>
          <img>...</img>
        </dataType2>
        <dataType2>
          <date1>2018-01-30T00:00:00.000+01:00</date1>
          <date2>2018-01-30T00:00:00.000+01:00</date2>
          <img>...</img>
        </dataType2>
        <otherFields>
          <field/>
          <field/>
          <field/>
        </otherFields>
      </process>
    </workflow1>    
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Using SoapUI groovy script I am able to copy data I wanted from the response to the request with the following code:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "Step1#Response" )
def requestHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "Step2#Request" )

// Remove all dataType1 from the request dom
for( item in requestHolder.getDomNodes( "//process/workflow1/dataType1" )){
  requestHolder.removeDomNodes("//"+item.nodeName)
}
// Remove all dataType2 from the request dom
for( item in requestHolder.getDomNodes( "//process/workflow1/dataType2" )){
  requestHolder.removeDomNodes("//"+item.nodeName)
}

def parentNode = requestHolder.getDomNode("//process/workflow1")
def otherFields = requestHolder.getDomNode("//process/workflow1/otherFields")
// Copy dataType1 into the request dom
for( item in responseHolder.getDomNodes( "//return/dataType1" )){
  def newNode = parentNode.getOwnerDocument().importNode(item,true)
  parentNode.insertBefore(newNode,otherFields)
}
// Copy dataType2 into the request dom
for( item in responseHolder.getDomNodes( "//return/dataType2" )){
  def newNode = parentNode.getOwnerDocument().importNode(item,true)
  parentNode.insertBefore(newNode,otherFields)
}

for( item in requestHolder.getDomNodes( "//process/workflow1/dataType2" )){
  // Copy //process/workflow1/dataType2/date1 to //process/workflow1/dataType2/date2
}


// Update the request
requestHolder.updateProperty()
context.requestContent = requestHolder.xml
```

But now, I wanted to copy dataType2.date1 to a new node called dataType2.date2 and I not able to do it.
I don't have any idea how to copy and insert this new node after date1. I have tried to use item to get child nodes but every function I tried is not define or the object I use is not the good one...

Any help ?